# Применение функции sorted для списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, сортировка

Есть список:

```
test = ['1', '0.1', '3', '80', 'abc', '0.4']
```

Как я могу отсортировать его, чтобы на выходе получился следующий результат:

```
test = ['0.1', '0.4', '1', '3', '80', 'abc']
```

Я делал следующим образом

```
test=sorted(test, key=lambda x: float(x) if x.isdigit() else x)
```

Но выпадает ошибка, так что не знаю как отсортировать вместе со словами('abc')

Comment: применить функцию sorted!

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что ну это совсем уже.

Comment: Просто `test = sorted(test)` без `key` уже даст `['0.1', '0.4', '1', '3', '80', 'abc']`.

Comment: Я отзываю голос за закрытие, потому что теперь совсем другое дело.

Comment: воспользуйтесь модулем [natsort](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/)

Comment: @MaxU Кстати да, забыл уже про него )

Answer (score 4):

Можно сделать вот так:

```
test = ['1', '0.1', '3', '80', 'abc', '0.41', '21', '0.2', 'xyz']

def get_key(x):
    try:
        return (float(x), '')
    except:
        return (float("inf"), x)

test=sorted(test, key=get_key)
print(test)
```

Вывод:

```
['0.1', '0.2', '0.41', '1', '3', '21', '80', 'abc', 'xyz']
```

Просто как строки весь список нельзя сортировать, тогда, например, будет такой порядок: '1', '21', '3', нужна именно сортировка чисел как чисел, а не как строк. В вашем то примере можно и как строки сортировать, но если будут другие входные данные, которые привёл я - так не заработает.

Comment: также можно использовать test.sort()

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться модулем [natsort](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/):

```
from natsort import natsorted   #  pip install natsort

test = ['123', '2000', 'Z', '0.1', '0.4', '1', '3', '80', 'abc']

natsorted(test)
>>> ['0.1', '0.4', '1', '3', '80', '123', '2000', 'Z', 'abc']
```

Answer (score 1):

Для сортировки списка содержащего `float`, `int`, `str` вы можете использовать встроенный метод sorted, c параметром `key=repr`.

Пример:

```
>>> test = ['1', '0.1', '3', '80', 'abc', '0.4']
>>> print(sorted(test, key=repr))
['0.1', '0.4', '1', '3', '80', 'abc']
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще вариант:

```py
test.sort(key=lambda x: float(x) if x.replace('.', '', 1).isdigit() else float('inf'))
```

Правда есть ограничения: только для положительных чисел.